# JVM getObjectSize example

Tags: java, jvm

I have some trouble on getting the size of an object in JVM. JDK 5 offer an interface `Instrumentation` to calculate through `premain()` function, but I do not know how to use it.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: You are likely to find using a memory profiler is a much easier way to do this (that is what it is designed for)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

the simplest and the most efficient solution is to use very small **sizeof** library

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.carrotsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-sizeof</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

you need to use this http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.carrotsearch/java-sizeof/0.0.2/com/carrotsearch/sizeof/RamUsageEstimator.java?av=f

**shallowSizeOf()** method or **sizeOf()**

That's really the simplest working fast solution i found on this topic so far...

Comment: Here is presentation from author of this library: http://www.slideshare.net/DawidWeiss/sizeofobject-how-much-memory-objects-take-on-jvms-and-when-this-may-matter?ref=http://cheremin.blogspot.com/2012/05/how-much-memory-objects-take-on-jvm-and.html

Answer (score 1):

Another open source project that may help you is [Jamm](https://github.com/jbellis/jamm) which uses a JVM agent as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here we have a very good article by ***Dustin Marx*** that I can refer you .

http://java.dzone.com/articles/estimating-java-object-sizes

Answer (score 0):

You might find it helpful to use the [MemoryMeasurer library](https://github.com/DimitrisAndreou/memory-measurer), which packages simple memory measurement into a relatively straightforward API.  (Alternatively, you can look at its source code to see how it uses instrumentation.)

Comment: the link leads to 404.